# TinyMCE is not defined Jquery

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Have been working on this error for 2 days and cannot get TinyMCE to work. I am using the jquery version of TinyMCE. Below is my HTML code with a form that contains a textarea.  I use Google Inspect Element and under the console tab i get the following error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined". Any help would be appreciated.

```
<form id="add_update_form" action="" method="POST" title="Add Blog">

<p class="feedback"></p>

<!-- <label>Created:</label>
<input type="text" name="created"> -->

<label>Title:</label>
<input type="text" name="title" class="input-block-level">

<label>Content:</label>
<textarea width="100%" rows="10" cols="10" name="content" class="input-block-level"></textarea>

<div class="clear"></div>

</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/portal/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea",
plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
    "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste moxiemanager"
],
toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are there any errors on the debug console? Also, try using a local copy of jquery instead of the cdn.

Comment: Yes the debug console error is "Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined (anonymous function)". I tried local and cdn with no success.

Comment: Is the JS file actually loading? Check the network tab in dev tools in the browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you are using the jquery version you'll need to set it up like a jquery plugin

```
$(function() {
   $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
    ...
   });
});
```

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/jquery_plugin.php

Comment: Thanks that fixed the error, didn't realize I had to use it like a plugin.

Answer (score 4):

I looked at this page: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/jquery_plugin.php
and clicked tab "View source" and noticed something.

If you are using TinyMCE as jQuery plugin, there is additional parameter required **script_url**, so your code should look like this:

```
$('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
   script_url: 'js/portal/tinymce/tinymce.min.js',
...
```

Other solution is to use non-jQuery version:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/portal/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

and then use old method to init the TinyMCE (as in your initial code):

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
...
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that TinyMCE js file is not loaded. Instead of:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/portal/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

Try the following:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/tinymce/4.0b2/jquery/jquery.tinymce.min.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Not sure why the tinymce jquery file is not loading.