# Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

i am using following code to integrate tinymce

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.7.9/jquery.tinymce.min.js" ></script>

tinyMCE.init({
              mode : "textareas",
              theme : "advanced",
              plugins : "emotions,spellchecker,advhr,insertdatetime,preview",

              // Theme options - button# indicated the row# only
              theme_advanced_buttons1 : "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,fontselect,fontsizeselect,formatselect",
              theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,|,code,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
              theme_advanced_buttons3 : "insertdate,inserttime,|,spellchecker,advhr,,removeformat,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions",
              theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
              theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
              theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
              theme_advanced_resizing : true
          });
```

following is the error i get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined

Please help me with this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907580/tinymce-is-not-defined-jquery

Comment: i used this one  instead of tinymce , https://summernote.org/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is tinyMCE.init , it should be tinymce.init.

** Note the change in tinyMCE(capital) and tinymce(small).

Answer (score 0):

References to variables in JavaScript are case-sensitive. Replace `tinyMCE` with `tinymce`.